# Android Development: Thread.sleep just slow down game

Tags: android, 2d, sleep, frame-rate, thread-sleep

I have a:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        synchronized (event)  
        {  

        try {
            Thread.sleep(16);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

          isDown = true;
        }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){

          isDown = true;
        }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

         isDown = false;
        }

        return true;
        } 

    }
```

Then in my `MainGame thread` I use `setCharacterPosition();`

```
 public void setCharacterPosition(){
    if(isDown){
CharacterX += 32;
}
    }
```

but this make my Character to run toooo quickly so i tried to add:

```
Thread.sleep(500);
```

Because i only want my character to increase with 32 every half a sencond.

IT works but bring my FPS down to 2-3.

How do i do it right?

//Simon

Comment: Why not decrease the increment value you are using (i.e. something lower than 32 maybe 5)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know little about Java or Android, but this seems like a wrong way to do it.

What you're after is setting up a Game Loop (a loop that continuously runs and updates the game logic, frame by frame).

This loop is executed on timed intervals (usually 60 frames per second, or maybe less on a mobile platform).

On each frame, you can scale the game object's movements based on the time elapsed since last frame.

This gives a scaled movement, irrelevant to the clock speed of the device you're using.

Read more abot game loops in these fine resources:

[Simple Java Android Game Loop](http://blorb.tumblr.com/post/236799414/simple-java-android-game-loop)

[Game Loop](http://aubykhan.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/android-game-programming-the-game-loop/)

[Android Game Loop](http://obviam.net/index.php/a-very-basic-the-game-loop-for-android/)

Comment: To add an easy example... character moves 10px per second... time since last frame 0.005s. CharacterX += 10 * 0.005f

Comment: Well basicly i increase by 32 because i have a grid and my character should not stand in middle between a line

Answer (score 0):

Android UI is based on Single Thread Model, so do not block UI Thread. Your onTouchEvent executes in UI Thread...when you call Thread.sleep you are making your UI thread to sleep for that specific period of time.

Hope this help. Ref: [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)